# Swift: arrayToTree() where array contains int and nil

Tags: swift, generics

I am learning tree on Leetcode. Need to prepare the testing data.

It is easy to convert the array to an organized node, where its elements are integers.

such as `[3, 9, 20, 15, 7]`

Here is my code:

```
extension Array where Element == Int{

func arrayToTree() -> TreeNode{
    var nodes = [TreeNode]()
    for num in 0..<self.count{
         nodes.append(TreeNode(self[num]))
    }

    var i = 0
    repeat{
        nodes[i].left = nodes[2 * i + 1]
        if self.count > 2 * i + 2 {
             nodes[i].right = nodes[2 * i + 2]
        }
        i+=1
    }while i < (self.count)/2

    return nodes.first!
  }
}
```

When the last level contains some nils , such as `[3, 9, 20, nil, nil, 15, 7]`

Here is the code:

```
extension Array where Element == Int?{

    func arrayToTree() -> TreeNode?{

        guard self.count > 0 else{
            return nil
        }
        var nodes = [TreeNode?]()
        for num in 0..<self.count{
            if let num = self[num]{
                nodes.append(TreeNode(num))
            }
            else{
                nodes.append(nil)
            }
        }
        var i = 0
        repeat {
            nodes[i]?.left = nodes[2 * i + 1]
            if self.count > 2 * i + 2 {
                nodes[i]?.right = nodes[2 * i + 2]
            }
            i += 1
        } while i < (self.count) / 2

        return nodes.first!
    }


}
```

How can I refactor this?

Such as combine them together using Swift Generic with some Protocol.

Comment: Could you add a link to the leetcode question or the number?

Comment: This is not a question. It's on improving auxiliary code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Simplifying `func arrayToTree()`

This

> ```
>    var nodes = [TreeNode?]()
>    for num in 0..<self.count{
>        if let num = self[num]{
>            nodes.append(TreeNode(num))
>        }
>        else{
>            nodes.append(nil)
>        }
>    }
> ```

creates a new array by *mapping* each element in `self` (an optional `Int`) to a new element (an optional `TreeNode`). That can be simplified to

```
let nodes = self.map { $0.map { TreeNode($0) } }
```

where the outer `Array.map` maps the given array to a new array, and the inner `Optional.map` maps an optional `Int` to an optional `TreeNode`.

The

> ```
>    var i = 0
>    repeat {
>        // ...
>        i += 1
>    } while i < (self.count) / 2
> ```

loop can be simplified to

```
for i in 0..<self.count/2 {
    // ...
}
```

The forced unwrapping

> ```
>    return nodes.first!
> ```

cannot crash – the `nodes` array cannot be empty at this point. I would still suggest to avoid it since later code changes might break the logic. It also makes it easier for future maintainers of the code to verify its correctness.

Actually the preceding code just results in an empty `nodes` array if the given list is empty. Therefore we can remove the initial `guard` and replace it by

```
guard let first = nodes.first else {
    return nil
}
return first
```

at the end of the method. This can be further shortened to

```
return nodes.first.flatMap { $0 }
```

Putting it together, the function would look like this:

```
func arrayToTree() -> TreeNode? {

    let nodes = self.map { $0.map { TreeNode($0) } }
    for i in 0..<self.count/2 {
        nodes[i]?.left = nodes[2 * i + 1]
        if self.count > 2 * i + 2 {
            nodes[i]?.right = nodes[2 * i + 2]
        }
    }

    return nodes.first.flatMap { $0 }
}
```

#### An alternative implementation

What you have is a way to create a `TreeNode`, and that is what *initializers* methods are for. Therefore I would put the code in a

```
public convenience init?(values: [Int?])
```

of the `TreeNode` class instead of an `Array` extension method. The usage would be

```
let list = [3, 9, 20, nil, nil, 15, 7]
if let tree = TreeNode(values: list) {
    // ...
}
```

And the task calls for a recursive implementation:

```
public convenience init?(values: [Int?], offset: Int = 0) {
    guard offset < values.count, let value = values[offset] else {
        return nil
    }
    self.init(value)
    self.left = TreeNode(values: values, offset: 2 * offset + 1)
    self.right = TreeNode(values: values, offset: 2 * offset + 2)
}
```

#### Making it generic

With the above changes it is now easy to replace `Int` by an arbitrary value type:

```
public class TreeNode<T> {
    public var val: T
    public var left: TreeNode?
    public var right: TreeNode?
    public init(_ val: T) {
        self.val = val
        self.left = nil
        self.right = nil
    }

    public convenience init?(values: [T?], offset: Int = 0) {
        guard offset < values.count, let value = values[offset] else {
            return nil
        }
        self.init(value)
        self.left = TreeNode(values: values, offset: 2 * offset + 1)
        self.right = TreeNode(values: values, offset: 2 * offset + 2)
    }
}
```